# How to add values from test steps in pytest excel report

Tags: excel, python-2.7, pytest

I am using pytest excel to run python test and generate test report in excel using below :

py.test --excelreport=report.xls test.py

Install excel plugin using :  pip install pytest-excel

I want to display the values from test steps to the excel report. How is it possible.
e.g. In below test step I want to display newNum value in the excel report

```
def subNumbers(fNum, sNum):
    newNum = fNum - sNum
    print newNum
```

Currently excel report is displayed as below:

```
SUITE NAME  TEST NAME   DESCRIPTION RESULT  DURATION    MESSAGE FILE NAME   MARKERS
TestSumFlow test_step1      PASSED  15.24737811     e_test.py
```

Answer (score 0):

you can write in "MARKERS" all you want. For this you must describe your test:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize(argnames, argvalues)
def test_sub_numbers(fNum, sNum):
    """ this test have blablabla """ 

    newNum = fNum - sNum
    print newNum
```

more info in [link](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/example/markers.html)